# How to integrate Python OpenCV code in android studio

Tags: android, python-3.x, android-studio, setup.py

I know only dex or .c file is able to integrate to android project in android studio.
But I don't know how to use .py file in android studio.
I have got one python code and should integrate into Java/Android.
Please let me know how to integrate the python code in Android Studio.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague of mine used https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/, it worked well for him. 
You can call your python functions directly from Java / Kotlin on Android. 
I don't know the details of exactly how he did it, but it was not too hard I think.